# Circular reasoning in a simple consequence of vector space definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

In books, after the definition of vector spaces, one usually proves simple consequences of it, such as $(-1)\cdot v=-v$.

One of these consequences is the following:

If $\alpha\cdot v=0$, then $\alpha=0$ or $v=0$.

Well, if $\alpha\neq 0$, then $\alpha^{-1}\cdot\alpha v=0$ and then $v=0$.

I am having a little trouble proving the other part. I tried:

If $v\neq 0$, then

\begin{equation}
v=v+\alpha\cdot v=1\cdot v+\alpha\cdot v=(1+\alpha)\cdot v=v.
\end{equation}

From the last equality, it would follow that $(1+\alpha)=1$ and hence $\alpha=0$.

However, doing this we are implictly assuming that $\alpha\cdot v=\beta\cdot v$ implies $\alpha=\beta$.

And to prove this, we would use that $(\alpha-\beta)\cdot v=0$ implies $\alpha-\beta=0$.

Can you see my problem? I'm arguing in a circular fashion.

Can someone correct me or help me out with an alternative argument? Thanks.

Comment: Unless you have not written down the problem, there is no other part, the sentence that begins with "Well" is a (somewhat condensed) full proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Andre says, your sentence beginning with "Well" constitutes a full proof. Allow me to explain. You wish to prove that if $\alpha v = 0$, then $\alpha = 0$ or $v=0$. You (implicitly) do the correct first step and assume that $\alpha v = 0$. Now we wish to conclude that $\alpha = 0$ or $v=0$. Let's break this into cases. Case 1: $\alpha = 0$, and we are done! Case 2: $\alpha \neq 0$, then $0 = \alpha^{-1} \alpha v = v$ and we are done. Since all cases have been covered, the proof is complete.

Note that you glazed over Case 1, and so you didn't realize that your proof was in fact (nearly) complete.

Comment: Oh, my bad, that was kind of obvious. I'm not sure if I'm allowed to keep asking questions in comments, but just out of curiosity: Is the above result not true for $R$-modules? I can't think of an alternative proof. Maybe there exists one and the above is just shorter. If not, any easy counter-examples?

Comment: Just answering my own comment: in abelian groups we can have torsion, so its not true.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha v=0$ and $v\neq 0$. Suppose it's also $\alpha \neq 0$. Then $\alpha^{-1}$ exists and we get the contradiction
$$0\neq v=1\cdot v=\alpha^{-1}(\alpha v)=\alpha^{-1} 0=0.$$